# Check if array contains different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

How can I make a native javascript function to detect different values in Array?

e.g:

```
const arr = [];
console.log(checkDiff(arr["A", "A", "A", "A")); // false
console.log(checkDiff(arr["A", "A", "A", "B")); // true
console.log(checkDiff(arr["B", "A", "C", "A")); // true
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) store unique values. Use `size` to get the number of unique elements. Return `false` if size is one.

```js
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "A"])); // false
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "B"])); // true
console.log(checkDiff(["B", "A", "C", "A"])); // true
console.log(checkDiff([])); // true

function checkDiff(a) {
  return new Set(a).size !== 1;
}
```

If you want to return `false` if the array is empty, you can:

```js
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "A"])); // false
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "B"])); // true
console.log(checkDiff(["B", "A", "C", "A"])); // true
console.log(checkDiff([])); // false

function checkDiff(a) {
  return a.length !== 0 && new Set(a).size !== 1;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Remove_duplicate_elements_from_the_array

Answer (score 3):

Use `every`:

```js
function checkDiff(arr) {
  return !arr.every(e => e == arr[0]);
}

console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "A"]));
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "B"]));
console.log(checkDiff(["B", "A", "C", "A"]));
```

Alternatively, make a new array from a `Set` and see if the `length` isn't 1:

```js
function checkDiff(arr) {
  return [...new Set(arr)].length != 1;
}

console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "A"]));
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "B"]));
console.log(checkDiff(["B", "A", "C", "A"]));
```

Comment: Simpler: `new Set(arr).size !==1` as in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450718/295783

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is an element which is not same as the first one.
[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
checkDiff = (arr) => arr.some(ele => ele !== arr[0]);

console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "A"])); // false
console.log(checkDiff(["A", "A", "A", "B"])); // true
console.log(checkDiff(["B", "A", "C", "A"])); // true
```